# "Authentication Failure" when calling a method on Remote Object in wpf

Tags: wpf, remoting, instance

I am developing an application which uses WindowsFormsApplicationBase to enforce Single Instance. I get the following error when calling a method on a Remote object. It works fine if I don't use Single Instance approach.

*System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: Authentication failure ---> System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: The connection was closed.
   at System.Net.Security.NegoState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStream.AuthenticateAsClient(NetworkCredential credential, String targetName, ProtectionLevel requiredProtectionLevel, TokenImpersonationLevel allowedImpersonationLevel)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp.TcpClientTransportSink.CreateAuthenticatedStream(Stream netStream, String machinePortAndSid)*

Here is my Code:

```
public class EntryPoint
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SingleInstanceManager sim = new SingleInstanceManager();
        sim.Run(args);
    }
}


public class SingleInstanceManager : WindowsFormsApplicationBase
{
    private App app;

    public SingleInstanceManager()
    {
        IsSingleInstance = true;
    }

    protected override bool OnStartup(Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.StartupEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        app = new App();
        app.InitializeComponent();
        app.Run();
        return false;
    }

    protected override void OnStartupNextInstance(StartupNextInstanceEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        base.OnStartupNextInstance(eventArgs);
        app.Activate();
    }
}
```

This is how I am invoking the Remoting object:

```
public Hashtable GetData(string[] arg1, string[] arg2)
{
    IDataProvider dataProvider = (IDataProvider )Activator.GetObject(typeof(IDataProvider ), "tcp://.....");

    Hashtable data = dataProvider.GetData(arg1, arg2);

    return data;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself.

I used the following to implement single instance(http://www.ai.uga.edu/mc/SingleInstance.html).

```
[STAThread]
static void Main()                  // args are OK here, of course
{
    bool ok;
    m = new System.Threading.Mutex(true, "YourNameHere", out ok);

    if (! ok)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Another instance is already running.");
        return;
    }

    Application.Run(new Form1());   // or whatever was there

    GC.KeepAlive(m);                // important!
}
```